# jQuery UI - Draggable/droppable snap to parent div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

Can anyone help me with this bit of code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tVzq9/2/

I'm trying to get the div '.boxArt' to snap to the parent div '.drop', but in the same way as it reverts (so it's smooth). At the moment it'll drop onto the div but won't fit it properly. Using "tolerance: 'fit'" for the drop div doesn't work as it's very hard to position exactly on it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/awsFU/

Use the [drop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) of the droppable to handle the animation of the draggable onto the droppable. Note that the `drop` callback function receives two parameters: `event` and `ui`. The draggable object is accessed via the `ui` parameter (`ui.draggable`) inside the `drop` callback. Then you can calculate the new position of the draggable from the current offsets of the draggable and droppable.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. :) Another question - is the draggable div actually moved to the div so that it can be detected? When one is placed onto another I want them to switch places. Would that be possible? Thanks again.

Comment: If you use something like Firebug, you will see that the `div`s aren't moved in the html - only their style is changed to modify their position. For what you want to do, you will probably have to check the position of the other draggable and move it when the first draggable is dropped onto the same location.